# how to use put method in map type in JAVA?

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a `Map` type variable

```
a = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
```

My question are:

1. For example, now I have `String b, String c`, how to use `put()` method to put it into the map? I don't know how to write the expression.
2. If I want to just put in a key, for example `String d`, and do not add any string to the value set, how to write it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this.

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> a = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
Integer i = 100; //say
String b = "str"; //say
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(i);
a.put(b,list);
```

Comment: Then later, if there is an other <b,i>, how to update the map? Should I first get the list linked to b, then add i, then put(b, list)? Is this correct and will update the list? Thank you!

Comment: If you are adding a new value to that associated with b then - you need to get the reference of list and just add it, don't put into map again. ex - `List<Integer> list = a.get("str"); list.add(2);`

Comment: I believe it will work. But could tell me the different between your method and just use the put method?

Comment: See, you put again then it'll be considered as duplicate key in map.

Comment: No,it will replace the old value. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put(K, V)